# R error in using HT approach

Tags: r, error-handling, plm

I am using trade data, and studying the export model. I want to use HT method, but it gives me this error. I have read across but I can't seem to fix it.

```
R <- pht(pdata$LnExport ~ pdata$LnGDP_L + pdata$capp + pdata$NRr + pdata$Index2 + pdata$EFI + pdata$lldpc| pdata$lldpc, data=pdata, model = "ht", na.action = FALSE) 
  Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data,  : 
    attempt to apply non-function
summary(R)
```

Comment: you dont need to reference `pdata$` in the formula, it will be evaluated in the environment of `data=pdata`. Also what does | refer to? usually I use +, -, :,* and ^.

Comment: The `|` is for multi-parts formulae from package `Formula`.